# ESLint SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags, Regex

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I tried to install Eslint extension plugin on my React App project, it appears that the EsLint Server stopped because I have an issue on the no-octal-escape.js file

`const match = node.raw.match(/^(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?\\([0-3][0-7]{1,2}|[4-7][0-7]|0(?=[89])|[1-7])/su)`

Node version : 12.13.1
Eslint version : 6.5.1

Can't figure it out

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpC9G.png)

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me came by using nvm in order to make sure I was actually using the last version by using the following command:

```
$ nvm install stable
```

I just ran into the exact same problem with my VueJS App project.

Even though I had an up to date node version, it turned out that I was not, in fact, using it. Which seems to be quite common: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12538

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by running VSCode updates.
Seems to be issue between Eslint extension and VsCode older versions.